# Simple Powershell Syntax

Tags: powershell

If I run this command:

```
$LinkedGPOs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*MyOU*"' | select -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
```

I get back a list of linked GPO's.
I need to run it with the filter looking for a variable, like this:

```
$LinkedGPOs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*$_.OrganizationalUnit*"' | select -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
```

I think it should be simple, but I've had no luck guessing around.

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: My rule of thumb is double quote outer, single quote inner for the AD cmdlet filters. mklement0 has an excellent answer with a full explanation if I can find it.

Comment: It isn't strictly a duplicate, but checking the question BenH referred to provided me with what I needed to deduce the answer.

Comment: @B.Ferguson: Your real problem was a misconception about PowerShell's string-expansion (string-interpolation) rules - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375